# How do I find the different sources of information I can use in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to find how long a user has been logged on or inactive for.

I have tried Active Directory, Event-Log, Get-WmiObject, Get-CimInstance, and a lot of other "gets".

I have looked online but couldn't find a way to find out the different sources I could look in.
How can I find out?

Comment: What did you actually try though and how did it fail? As for WMI, `Win32_LoggedOnUser` and `Win32_LogonSession` could be a start.

Comment: That said, starting out with PowerShell I often ran `gwmi -List | where { $_.Name -like "*<term_related_to_my_topic>*" }` to find what WMI classes might be relevant for me and my particular task. So, in your case that could be `gwmi -List | where { $_.Name -like "*user*" }`.

Comment: Win32_LoggedOnUser for some reason didn't always give me a name.  We thought it could be because it was deleted after a certain number of days  

That's a really useful command, thanks!  It doesn't seem to show things like active directory at the moment, but maybe it would work on the admin account when I can test that.

Comment: The class `Win32_LoggedOnUser` is for current sessions against a particular host (localhost if no remote computer was defined when running Get-WmiObject), and has no knowledge about now logged off, but sometime in the past logged on user sessions (as far as I know). Compare with running `quser.exe` in cmd, or `quser.exe /server:<remote server>`. `wmic /node: "localhost" computersystem get username` is another way.